# How do i update a table column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to update one of my tables but i get a syntax error. For example my query:

```
 update micros set tabular =  select count (b.the_geom) from trees a, streets b where st_contains(b.the_geom,t.the_geom) group by t.roots;
```

The error message I receive is:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural thing to do would be:

```
update micros
    set tabular = st_contains(b.the_geom, t.the_geom)::int
    from trees a, streets b;
```

That said, the logic doesn't make sense.  It would seem that you would want *some* join condition among the three tables.